# Как применить фильтр в шаблоне django

Tags: python, django

### views.py

```
def autificat_user(request, pk):
    id_user = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    user_list = Profile.objects.all()
    for tes in user_list:
        print("user_list:",tes)
        if tes.friend.filter(user2=id_user):
            print(id_user,": to friends:", tes)
```

> **tes.friend.filter(user2=id_user)** <<Вот этот фильтр нужно в шаблоне применить, он проверяет нахожусь ли я у пользователя в друзьях.

### Шаблон .html

````
```{% for users in user_list %}
    <h2>{{ users }} друзей:{{ users.friend.all.count }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ users.friend|filter__user2:id_user }}</h3>
{% endfor %}```
````

**{{ users.friend|filter__user2:id_user }}** <<Сюда нужен фильтр но у меня выдаёт ошибку Invalid filter: 'filter_user2'

### models.py

Вдруг понадобится

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    friend = models.ManyToManyField('Friends', blank=True, related_name='friend') # внешний ключ
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user2')
```